# Document title, author and date lost when using officedown::rdocx and reference_docx

Tags: r-markdown, officedown

If I do not use a word reference file and define tittle , author and date I get the standard title page.

```
 ---
 title: Report Title 
 author: Ross 
 date: 3/3/2022 
 output: officedown:: rdocx_document
 ---
```

however if I nominate a company  template company_report_template.docx

```
---
title: Report Title 
author: Ross 
date: 3/3/2022 
output: 
  officedown::rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: company_report_template.docx
---
```

The title, author and date are printed out in the rendered word document with no style.

It appears the yaml metadata is lost during rendering.

Comment: If you have a space between `officedown::` and `rdocx_document` it won't work out correctly. You need write it as one long string: `officedown::rdocx_document`

Comment: Thanks. That was a typo. Thanks I will edit.

Comment: you need to define those styles in your template. If the style are not defined they can not be applied